# Did the Pnei Menachem of Ger have a sharp sense of humor?

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures, chassidic-rebbe, humor

A Satmar Chossid relayed this story to me:

> [The previous Gerer Rebbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchas_Menachem_Alter) had a policy that he did not want a newly married chatan to attend his Shabbat tisch during his 1st year of marriage. One Shabbat, he saw a chatan at the Shabbat tisch. The Rebbe walked up to him and gave him a a piece of kugel. Then, he said, "Here's a piece of kugel. Make 'shehakol'. Then go home to your wife and make 'borei nefashos'".

I think it's a great story! I can't verify its authenticity. But, I'm curious if the Rebbe was known for having such a sharp sense of humor.

Comment: Wow. That's bolder than any joke I've heard a rabbi say. "bolder" is lashon naki btw.

Comment: @ClintEastwood - The Rebbe WAS using lashon naki :-)

Comment: I wonder if the talmid understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can not verify this specific story, the Rabbi's of the ger dynasty have always been known for their sharp wit. As the first Rabbi of Ger ["was a preeminent disciple of the Kotzker Rebbe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_of_Kotzk) who "was well known for his incisive and down-to-earth philosophies, and sharp-witted sayings. He appears to have had little patience for false piety or stupidity".